# Strange behaviour of arcs with pgfplots v1.11

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arc

This only happened after I updated to latest pgfplots version v 1.11 and used to be compiled with a fine looking result.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usetikzlibrary{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}      

        \begin{axis}[%
            scale mode = scale uniformly,
            grid=none,
            xmin=-1.2,
            xmax= 1.2,
            ymin=-.55,
            ymax= .55,
            xtick={-1,-0.5,...,1},
            ytick={-1,-0.5,...,1},
            minor y tick num=3,
            minor x tick num=1,
            width= .75\textwidth,
            height=.33\textwidth,
            scale only axis,
            xlabel={x},
            ylabel={y}
        ]

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{.5};
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\gamma}{35};
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\beta}{20};

            \draw [black!80] (0,0) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=\gamma-90, radius=\radius];

            \draw [ultra thick] (0,-0.5) arc[start angle=-90, end angle=180, radius=\radius];

        \end{axis}          
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I get the following result, which I can't understand. Where is the distortion coming from?
I should see a nice 3/4 circle, shouldn't I?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in `pgfplots` 1.11: it comes with a new feature which allows to write `(1,1)` instead of `(axis cs:1,1)`. Unfortunately, that feature was applied in a wrong way when it comes to arcs. In other words: yes, this is a bug in pgfplots 1.11 .

It has already been addressed and will become part of pgfplots 1.12 (planned for January 2015). Your example works fine (without modifications) in the prerelease version of `pgfplots` 1.12 .

---

A workaround appears to be:

1. use `compat=1.10`
2. use `disabledatascaling`
3. use `(axis cs:0,0)` instead of `(0,0)` .

   ```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
   \usepackage{amsmath}

   %\usetikzlibrary{}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}      

       \begin{axis}[%
           disabledatascaling,
           scale mode = scale uniformly,
           grid=none,
           xmin=-1.2,
           xmax= 1.2,
           ymin=-.55,
           ymax= .55,
           xtick={-1,-0.5,...,1},
           ytick={-1,-0.5,...,1},
           minor y tick num=3,
           minor x tick num=1,
           width= .75\textwidth,
           height=.33\textwidth,
           scale only axis,
           xlabel={x},
           ylabel={y}
       ]

           \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{.5};
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\gamma}{35};
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\beta}{20};

           \draw [black!80] (axis cs:0,0) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=\gamma-90, radius=\radius];

           \draw [ultra thick] (axis cs:0,-0.5) arc[start angle=-90, end angle=180, radius=\radius];

       \end{axis}          
   \end{tikzpicture}%
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is some problem about units when `pgfplots` is processing the coordinates of, say, control points. (On the other hand, the end points of your arc are at the right place.) In this case, I found that specifying a unit make the arc more like an arc. For instance:

```
\draw[black!80](0,0)arc[start angle=90,delta angle=\gamma-90,radius=\radius pt];
```

But this then ignores `axis cs` the (default) coordinate system since you assign an explicit length. [After some works](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213901/about-the-actual-meaning-of-pgfplotsunitxlength-macro-from-the-pgfplots-package)  you can extract the scaling factor and multiply `\radius` by it. Now everything looks fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[scale mode=scale uniformly,xmin=-1.2,xmax= 1.2,ymin=-.55,ymax= .55]
        \pgfplotsextra{
            \pgfplotstransformdirectionx{1}
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ex}{\pgfmathresult*\pgfplotsunitxlength}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{.5*\ex};\pgfmathsetmacro{\gamma}{35};}
        \draw[black!80](0,0)arc[start angle=90,delta angle=\gamma-90,radius=\radius pt];
        \draw[ultra thick](0,-0.5)arc[start angle=-90,end angle=180,radius=\radius pt];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solves the issue, but I happen to think that this can't be the real solution. It's more of a workaround, don't you think?

I hope Christian looks stumbels over this and has something to point out. Thanks for the help though! I appreciate it.

Comment: @goeck It is a workaround. Consider to submit a bug report if it really bothers you. I posted this answer but not just calling a bug because specifying an explicit radius makes more sense. Since the x-vector and the y-vector may be of different length, one should not expect `tikz` to use either one as radius by default. (Although `ellipse[x radius=1,y radius=2]` makes sense, and compiles.)